# Pandas dataframe replace

Tags: python

New to Pandas and python and have a question on replacing multiple unicode characters within an entire data frame.  Using python 2.7 and importing from an excel sheet.  My desire is to replace all non-ascii characters with their ascii equivalent or nothing.

examples:
u'SHOGUN JAPANESE \u2013 GRAND'
u'COMFORT INN & SUITES\xa0STONE MOUNTAIN'

This works, but is cumbersome:

```
rawdf = rawdf["Account_Name"].str.upper().str.replace(u'\u2013', ' ').str.replace(u'\xa0', '-') + "|" + rawdf["COID"].str.upper()
```

This did not work:

```
rawdf = rawdf.replace(u'\u2013', ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an encode/decode cycle like so:

```
rawdf["Account_Name"].str..encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')
```

The use of 'ignore' makes characters that cannot be represented in ascii be dropped. The intermediate representation is bytes, so we need to encode it back to strings again.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but now because of the ignore, the characters as you mention were dropped.  I actually need to do a replacement.  The downstream process needs to compare raw_set_1 to clean_set_2 to give me the difference.  Currently the difference is caused by these unique characters.  Other thoughts?

Comment: You can use 'replace' instead, which will keep the character position and fill it, I believe, with a "?".